# "x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang" not found when execute GoLang code

Tags: macos, rest, go, gcc, clang

I'm fresh to golang and just copied a simple piece of code about using gin to build a restful api with golang. And once I build the code, this error shows:

```
# runtime/cgo
cgo: C compiler "x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang" not found: exec: "x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I think it's related to the dependency of gin, since if simply writing "hello world" can work.

I use macos ventura 13.2.1 with m2 chip, not sure if this is also the reason.

Can anyone help me resolve this error? Do I need to install some older version of gcc/clang?

Answer (score 0):

based on your title you're using macOS for sure. In short, you should use Homebrew to install go than other package managers. Once you install it, run this to have a out-of-box go:

```
brew install go
```

It will not work if you install go via Conda (in my case using mamforge didn't work).